# How to validate HHMMSS in regex

Tags: java

I tried like this it is not working, but not works for value 005959 format HHMMSS

```
if(Pattern.matches("^([0-23])([0-59])([0-59])$", value))
{
    SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHMMSS");
    dformat.setLenient(false);
    dformat.parse(value);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try to parse with SimpleDateFormat and catch any exception?

Comment: Since when is 016060 a valid timestamp? That would equate to 020100

Comment: exception handling that can be achived by second validation initially would like to do using regex.

Comment: thanks pal edited as you wished.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do numeric ranges like that. To validate 1-24 (what's wrong with 00 by the way? and since when was 60 valid in the other positions?) you'd need to do it digit by digit like this:

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])
```

That is, if the first digit is 0 then 1-9 must follow; if 1 then any can follow; if 2 then 0-4 must follow. But why use Regex for this anyway? In full:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])(0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60)(0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60)$
```

But still, check comments on 0 and 60 values...

Comment: System.out.println("dateFormateValidate :"+Pattern.matches("(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])","016060"));  this returns false why.....

Comment: Because this is only the Regex for the hour part. You will need to extend the pattern for minutes and seconds in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The correct regular expression should be:

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3])[0-5]\d[0-5]\d$
```

as already noted in the comment 60 is not a valid minutes nor second, and 24 is not a valid hour.

In a world where hours goes to 1 to 24 and minutes from 1 to 60, then you should use:

```
^(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-4])(0[1-9]|[1-5]\d|60)(0[1-9]|[1-5]\d|60)$
```